# Plot one time series graph from two data.frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, plot, time-series

I have two data.frame, number one called GPP_DT:

```
     Dataset  TIMESTAMP GPP_NT_VUT_REF TA_F_MDS_QC TA_F_MDS_NIGHT TA_F_MDS_NIGHT_SD TA_F_MDS_NIGHT_QC
     1       1 2019-01-01    0.492           1          2.973             1.040                 1
     2       1 2019-01-02    0.419           1          2.730             1.847                 1
     3       1 2019-01-03    0.337           1          1.528             1.955                 1
     4       1 2019-01-04    0.438           1         -1.190             1.316                 1 
     
     ... ... ... till 01-01-2021
```

and nuber two called GPP_WRF_Daily:

```
                   date      GPP_WRF GPP_WRF_mean
         1   2019-01-01 8.630011e-05    0.3106804
         2   2019-01-02 9.069429e-05    0.3264994
         3   2019-01-03 7.207996e-05    0.2594879
         4   2019-01-04 6.910294e-05    0.2487706
         
         ... ... till 01-01-2020
```

I would to plot these two datasets (variables: GPP_NT_VUT_REF and GPP_WRF_mean in y-axis, time (TIMESTAMP and date) as the x-axis) using R in the same timeseries plot.

My problems are:

1. They don't have equal intervals of time (so I need to cut the year 2020 and 2021 from the first data.frame and 2020 from the second data.frame).
2. I don't know how to realize one timeseries from two different data.frame.

Someone could help me?

Thank you in advance,
Beatrice

Answer (score 1):

I've made up some similar data with appropriate dates to show how this could work with the `inner_join`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(clock)

GPP_DT <- tibble(
  timestamp = date_seq(as.Date("2019-01-01"),
    to = as.Date("2021-01-01"), by = duration_days(1)
  ),
  gpp_nt = rnorm(732, 10, 10)
)


GPP_WRF_Daily <- tibble(
  date = date_seq(as.Date("2019-01-01"),
    to = as.Date("2020-01-01"), by = duration_days(1)
  ),
  gpp_wrf = rnorm(366, 10, 10)
)

combined <- GPP_DT |> 
  inner_join(GPP_WRF_Daily, by = c("timestamp" = "date"))

combined
#> # A tibble: 366 × 3
#>    timestamp  gpp_nt gpp_wrf
#>    <date>      <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1 2019-01-01   9.75    2.17
#>  2 2019-01-02  13.3     6.36
#>  3 2019-01-03  17.6    13.8 
#>  4 2019-01-04  13.6    -6.03
#>  5 2019-01-05   6.11   26.0 
#>  6 2019-01-06  -3.88    2.16
#>  7 2019-01-07  13.0     6.83
#>  8 2019-01-08 -15.9    18.7 
#>  9 2019-01-09   4.00   -5.50
#> 10 2019-01-10  22.5     3.80
#> # … with 356 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I've tried your method but doesn't work, thanks anyway